# Max in list python code not showing off the max

Tags: python

```
my_list = [5, 2, -5, 10, 23, -21]
def max_int_in_list(my_list):
    highest=my_list[0]
    for num in my_list:
        if num > highest:
            highest = num
        return highest
print (max_int_in_list(my_list))
```

the output is 5 every time what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: The `return` statement should not be in the loop. You're returning  from the first iteration.

Comment: `return highest` should be 1 indentation level down. Currently it's inside your for loop.

Comment: Advice for future: add `print` statements to your code to help you debug things like this -- "`print` debugging" is by far the most common and often the easiest and quickest way to debug your code. Even professionals with decades of experience do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that you are return highest inside for loop. In order to find the highest you must let the loop run after that the function should return highest value . In your case the loop runs for the very first time and as the value of highest is my_list[0] i.e 5 so it returns 5 as the highest value .
Make your code as follows:

```
my_list = [5, 2, -5, 10, 23, -21]
def max_int_in_list(my_list):
    highest=my_list[0]
    for num in my_list:
        if num > highest:
           highest = num
    return highest

print (max_int_in_list(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the return statement is return in for block so even if condition is not fulfilled it will return the value of highest when loop is over and return statement through us out of ruction with the "highest"(variable)  value

so now we need to wait for "for loop" to end and change the value of "highest"(variable) and the return the the value of highest

```
my_list = [5, 2, -5, 10, 23, -21]
def max_int_in_list(my_list):
    highest=my_list[0]
    for num in my_list:
        if num > highest:
            highest = num
    return highest
print (max_int_in_list(my_list))
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.